# VBA in Access 2010 - Run-time Error 430

Tags: sql, sql-server, vba, ms-access, listbox

I’m getting a Run-time error '430':  Class does not support Automation or does not support expected interface" on this line of code `Set Me.lstResults.Recordset = rs` or this `Set Me![frmM_SearchForDocumentsSubForm].Form.Recordset = rs`.  I am trying to get the ADO Recordset based on a SQL stored procedure to appear in an unbound Listbox or Subform of an Access form.  I’m on Win 7 Machine using Access 2010 connecting to SQL Server 2008:

On_Click event:

```
Private Sub cmdRun_Click()
'On Error Resume Next

    Dim strSQL As String

    'Stored procedure + parameters called from form
    strSQL = "Exec sqlsp_searchalltables " & Me.txtTables & _
       ", " & "'%" & Me.txtSearchTerm & "%'"

    OpenMyRecordset rs, strSQL

    'debug - view procedure
    Me.lblQuery.Caption = strSQL
    Me.Repaint

    Set Me.lstResults.Recordset = rs
    'or this
    'Set Me![frmM_SearchForDocumentsSubForm].Form.Recordset = rs
End Sub
```

I found some solutions for this error on the web and tried all of them to no avail.  Most suggested checking the references which I did and verified.

I am able to successfully connect to the SQL server and have the results display in both a Listbox and Subform when I use DAO Querydef and a passthrough query or if I use this .listbox method:

```
With Me.lstResults
    Do
       strItem = rs.Fields("CLIENT_ID").Value
       .AddItem strItem
       rs.MoveNext
    Loop Until rs.EOF
End With
```

I would prefer not to use the DAO method because I found I need the coding flexibility of ADO especially with connecting to multiple Recordsets in SQL.  Thoughts?

FYI:  My `OpenMyRecordset` public function in Module:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Global con As New ADODB.Connection
Global rs As ADODB.Recordset
Global NoRecords As Boolean

Public Enum rrCursorType
    rrOpenDynamic = adOpenDynamic
    rrOpenForwardOnly = adOpenForwardOnly
    rrOpenKeyset = adOpenKeyset
    rrOpenStatic = adOpenStatic
End Enum

Public Enum rrLockType
    rrLockOptimistic = adLockOptimistic
    rrLockReadOnly = adLockReadOnly
End Enum

Public Function OpenMyRecordset(rs As ADODB.Recordset, strSQL As String, Optional rrCursor As rrCursorType, _
    Optional rrLock As rrLockType, Optional bolClientSide As Boolean) As ADODB.Recordset

    If con.STATE = adStateClosed Then
        con.ConnectionString = "ODBC;Driver={SQL Server};Server=mysqlsvr;DSN=RecordsMgmt_SQLDB;UID=XXX;Trusted_Connection=Yes;DATABASE=RecordsManagementDB;"
        con.Open
    End If

    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
    With rs
        .ActiveConnection = con
            .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .CursorType = IIf((rrCursor = 0), adOpenDynamic, rrCursor)
        .LockType = IIf((rrLock = 0), adLockOptimistic, rrLock)
        .Open strSQL
        If .EOF And .BOF Then
            NoRecords = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    End With

End Function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely do not have to do the looping method to just to populate the listbox.  I'm not familiar with the `OpenMyRecordset` command you used, but I suspect that something in its functionality is what is causing this error (i.e., it's not opening the recordset in a manner compatible with the listbox).  This is how I connected to a local instance of SQL Server Express and was able to populate a listbox.

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

With cn
    .ConnectionString = _
        "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;" & _
        "Initial Catalog=Northwind;Trusted_Connection=yes"
    .Open
End With

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

With rs
    Set .ActiveConnection = cn
    .Source = "SELECT FirstName, LastName FROM Employees"
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    .Open
End With

Set Me.lstTest.Recordset = rs

Set rs = Nothing
Set cn = Nothing
```

You will have to make sure that you have the Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects Library reference enabled in your project.

Comment: The `OpenMyRecordSet` calls a public function in a module that delares the rs object.  Looking at your code I think I need to change the `.LockType` and `.CursorType`.  I'll get back to your and let you know if that does it.

Comment: Okay, changing the `LockType` and `CursorType` to `adLockOptimistic` (prev. adLockReadOnly) and `adOpenDyamic` (prev. adOpenStatic), respectively worked.  I no longer get the Run-Time 430, but now I'm getting "Run time error 7965: the object you entered is not a valid recordset property", which references the same line of code: `Set Me.lstResults.Recordset = rs`.

Comment: Are you able to perform other recordset functions on `rs` without any other manipulation?  (Since your DAO example you mentioned changing the query).  If it is a recordset, it may not be one that's compatible with a listbox.  Hard to say, since you have somewhat of a "black box" with the `OpenMyRecordset` function...

Comment: Yes, I can successfully perform the looping method to populate the listbox.  I've edited my question to include the `OpenMyRecordset` function.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I was able to get rid of the error by removing the `IF..THEN..ELSE` statement referencing the `.CursorLocation` in my public function.  Now it only read `.CursorLocation = adUseClient`. Viola, it now works perfectly!