# VBA: How to add entire row of recordset into form list

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, recordset

I have Excel VBA code that runs a select query on an access database and returns a recordset. The connection works fine. When I get the recordset, I can access each field in each row fine. Here is what I am currently using:

```
Sub accessSelect(sql)
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Call accessConnection

With rs
    .Open sql, conn
End With

Do While Not rs.EOF
    'rtvEditForm.rtvList is a list box.
    rtvEditForm.rtvList.AddItem rs(1) & " - " & rs(2)
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
End Sub
```

I want to be able to throw the whole `rs` in the `rtvEditForm.rtvList` without having to refer to each field. I've tried `rtvEditForm.rtvList.AddItem rs`, but that does not work because I get a "Type Mismatch" error.

Seems simple but I just can't figure this out. How would I do that with my current code?

Comment: What kind of control is `rtvList`?

Comment: `rtvList` is a list box. Updated my original post.

Comment: i dont believe there is, but you can do for f=0 to rs.fields.count-1:strToAdd =strToAdd & rs.fields(f).value & ",":next f:cbo.AddItem strToAdd

Comment: Oh wait....is the listbox an ActiveX listbox on an Excel sheet or is in on an Access form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to do any looping. A listbox has a recordset property which can be [bound to an ADO recordset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20429921/vba-in-access-2010-run-time-error-430).

```
Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection

Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

With rs
    Set .ActiveConnection = cn
    .Source = sql
    .LockType = adLockOptimistic
    .CursorType = adOpenKeyset
    .Open
End With

Set Me.rtvList.Recordset = rs
rtvList.ColumnCount = rs.Fields.Count
```